# Editing Json files via node.js from the html input tag(Front end (angularJs+Html))

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, html

I have a bunch of json array files which I read and display in form of a table. Only the header of the table which are the keys of the json object need to editable. So the user could choose his own header and that need to be changed in the json file. My server side code is with node.js and front end with angularJs+html. For the following json file.

```js
[
{"name":"item 1", "id": 1},
{"name":"item 2", "id": 2}
]
```

Below is the picture of how my table looks like.
[image]

P.S: I have seen many questions regarding this but most of them suggests writing the whole file again with fs.write.
I am asking for a way that I can only change the keys of the json objects through header input of the table.

Comment: without storing those changes?

Comment: Your question is not clear. It looks like you've only written the background but there're no question and problem described.

Comment: The question is how could i change the json object keys with the input from the front end without writing the whole json file again.

Comment: @Hitmands: I want to store changes to the json file. i-e only the json object keys through input from front end.

Comment: you can parse the `json` as a text file, then with a `RegExp` update just what you want but it would be definitely more easy to pass the whole json back and rewrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model` with header and get the data in your angular controller.Then using `$http` post your updated data. And update value of your keys.

Comment: I have got the the data to my angular controller but i am looking for a way to replace the old keys with these new keys. Like fs.write is one method but with that i have to write the whole json file again not only the new keys.